# My 2012 Imprezza unpairs my phone every time I turn off car

Tags: bluetooth

It used to unpair a few times a year. Now it's every time I turn off car. Is there a fix for this problem?

Comment: What phone are you using? Do you have a different phone than you were using previously?

Answer (score 1):

For my radio I noticed that whenever I was working on the car and unplugged the battery my Bluetooth devices would afterwards unpair and I would have to reconnect them again. Maybe your car radio has a low-power wire connecting it to your car battery when its off or has its own battery keeping its memory. I would check if the radio battery is dead or if the wire is disconnected somewhere.